# AWS Redshift purge policy automation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

AWS Redshift team recommend using TRUNCATE in order to clean up a large table.
I have a continuous EC2 service that keeps adding rows to a table. I would like to apply some purging mechanism, so that when the cluster is near full it will auto delete old rows (say using the index column).

- Is there some best practice for doing that?
- Do I need to write my own code to handle that? (if so is there already a Python script for that that I can use e.g. in a Lambda function?)

Comment: Are you OK with losing rows from the table? How would you determine the rows to purge (eg date field)? Have you considered [Using Time Series Tables - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/vacuum-time-series-tables.html) instead of one large table?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common practice when dealing with continuous data is to create a separate table for each month, eg `Sales-2018-01`, `Sales-2018-02`.

Then create a `VIEW` that combines the tables:

```
CREATE VIEW sales AS
SELECT * FROM Sales-2018-01
UNION
SELECT * FROM Sales-2018-02
```

Then, create a new table each month and remove the oldest month from the View. This effectively gives a 12-month rolling view of the data.

The benefit is that data does not have to be deleted from tables (which would then require a `VACUUM`). Instead, the old table can simply be dropped, or kept around for historical reporting with a different View.

See: [Using Time Series Tables - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/vacuum-time-series-tables.html)